# How to extract group of strings and append it at the bottom of the file

Tags: unix, awk, sed, paste, cut

Good day,

I have a file which displays like this:

```
Bin   1 = 5778    669  753  731  743  752  727  736  667    
Bin   5 =    2      2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     Bin   7 =   63     36    5    1    1    5    1    5    9    
Bin   9 =    0      0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     Bin  24 =    2      0    0    0    0    0    0    0    2    
Bin  31 =    0      0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     Bin  47 =   28      2    4    6    1    2    5    3    5    
Bin  70 =    1      0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0     Bin  95 =    1      0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    
Bin 120 =    1      0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     Bin 121 =  162     49   13   11   10    3   10   12   54    
Bin 131 =    7      1    1    2    0    0    1    0    2     Bin 133 =    3      0    0    0    0    0    0    0    3    
Bin 141 =    6      0    0    0    1    0    1    2    2     Bin 560 =    1      0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    
Bin 620 =    1      0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0     Bin 630 =    2      0    0    1    0    0    0    0    1    
Bin 1250 =    1     0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0     Bin 1410 =    1     0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    
Bin 2004 =    1     0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     Bin 2240 =    1     0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    
Bin 2247 =    1     0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0     Bin 2300 =    1     0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    
Bin 2309 =    1     0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0     Bin 2310 =    3     1    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    
Bin 2602 =    1     0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
```

I would like to cut the 2nd "Bin" pattern along with it's value on the right side and paste it at the bottom of the file and then sort it later. Appreciate your help on this problem of mine. Im just new in unix commands and still learning it. Thanks in advance.

I would like to have an output like this.

```
Bin   1 = 5778    669  753  731  743  752  727  736  667    
Bin   5 =    2      2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     
Bin   7 =   63     36    5    1    1    5    1    5    9    
Bin   9 =    0      0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     
Bin  24 =    2      0    0    0    0    0    0    0    2    
Bin  31 =    0      0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     
Bin  47 =   28      2    4    6    1    2    5    3    5    
Bin  70 =    1      0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0     
Bin  95 =    1      0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    
Bin 120 =    1      0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     
Bin 121 =  162     49   13   11   10    3   10   12   54    
Bin 131 =    7      1    1    2    0    0    1    0    2     
Bin 133 =    3      0    0    0    0    0    0    0    3    
Bin 141 =    6      0    0    0    1    0    1    2    2     
Bin 560 =    1      0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    
Bin 620 =    1      0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0     
Bin 630 =    2      0    0    1    0    0    0    0    1    
Bin 1250 =    1     0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0     
Bin 1410 =    1     0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    
Bin 2004 =    1     0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     
Bin 2240 =    1     0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    
Bin 2247 =    1     0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0     
Bin 2300 =    1     0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    
Bin 2309 =    1     0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0     
Bin 2310 =    3     1    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    
Bin 2602 =    1     0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
```

regard,Mike

Comment: show your current effort and post the desired result

Comment: hi @RomanPerekhrest, sorry to say that I haven't come up with any solution yet, ive been reading about sed and awk but I somehow im getting overwhelmed and just dont know how to start, sorry for that

Comment: then do the 2nd action: *post the desired result*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short ***awk*** approach:

```
awk 'NF>12{ $13= ORS $13 }1' file | column -t
```

- `NF` - total number of fields
- `NF>12` - according to your expected result the maximal number of fields is 12. *Non-whitespace* sequence is treated as a field
- `$13= ORS $13` - breaking up the record at 13th field with record separator `ORS` (newline character)

The output:

```
Bin  1     =  5778  669  753  731  743  752  727  736  667
Bin  5     =  2     2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
Bin  7     =  63    36   5    1    1    5    1    5    9
Bin  9     =  0     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
Bin  24    =  2     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    2
Bin  31    =  0     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
Bin  47    =  28    2    4    6    1    2    5    3    5
Bin  70    =  1     0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
Bin  95    =  1     0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
Bin  120   =  1     0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
Bin  121   =  162   49   13   11   10   3    10   12   54
Bin  131   =  7     1    1    2    0    0    1    0    2
Bin  133   =  3     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    3
Bin  141   =  6     0    0    0    1    0    1    2    2
Bin  560   =  1     0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
Bin  620   =  1     0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
Bin  630   =  2     0    0    1    0    0    0    0    1
Bin  1250  =  1     0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
Bin  1410  =  1     0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
Bin  2004  =  1     0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
Bin  2240  =  1     0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
Bin  2247  =  1     0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
Bin  2300  =  1     0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
Bin  2309  =  1     0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
Bin  2310  =  3     1    1    0    0    0    0    0    1
Bin  2602  =  1     0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: hi @RomanPerekhrest, your code works, thanks a lot, mind if you can explain how it works, thanks again

Comment: @Mike, see my details

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, i understand now. Again, really appreciate the help

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest That's a nice solution, you got there. Could you explain what the 1 after the curly brace means?

Comment: @fancyPants, awk evaluates that argument numerically (equivalent to `print if 1 != 0`)

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/ \(Bin.*\)$/\n\1/g' file | sort -k 2 -n > outputfile
```

This searches for a string beginning with a space followed by "Bin" and whatever characters till the rest of the line.
The part that is put in escaped parantheses, can be referenced in the replace part of the command with `\1`. There you insert a newline before it.

The sort part takes the arguments

- -k 2 (sorting on the second column)
- -n (numerical sort)

Output:

```
# sed 's/ \(Bin.*\)$/\n\1/g' your_file | sort -k 2 -n
Bin   1 = 5778    669  753  731  743  752  727  736  667
Bin   5 =    2      2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
Bin   7 =   63     36    5    1    1    5    1    5    9
Bin   9 =    0      0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
Bin  24 =    2      0    0    0    0    0    0    0    2
Bin  31 =    0      0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
Bin  47 =   28      2    4    6    1    2    5    3    5
Bin  70 =    1      0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
Bin  95 =    1      0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
Bin 120 =    1      0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
Bin 121 =  162     49   13   11   10    3   10   12   54
Bin 131 =    7      1    1    2    0    0    1    0    2
Bin 133 =    3      0    0    0    0    0    0    0    3
Bin 141 =    6      0    0    0    1    0    1    2    2
Bin 560 =    1      0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
Bin 620 =    1      0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
Bin 630 =    2      0    0    1    0    0    0    0    1
Bin 1250 =    1     0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
Bin 1410 =    1     0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
Bin 2004 =    1     0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
Bin 2240 =    1     0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
Bin 2247 =    1     0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
Bin 2300 =    1     0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
Bin 2309 =    1     0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
Bin 2310 =    3     1    1    0    0    0    0    0    1
Bin 2602 =    1     0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: hi @fancyPants, i tried your code but it just added an "n" at the beginning of the line. There's no space in front of the Bin string, can you amend it, thanks for the input

Comment: Have you copy&pasted my code? Sounds like you forgot the backslash before the n.

Comment: yeah I copied and pasted them. I did again but the outcome was the same

Comment: Perhaps `sed 's/  *Bin/\nBin/;s/ *$//' file | sort -k2n` will also remove spaces from the end of each record. No need for the `g` flag as there will only be at most one match per line. N.B. this is tested with GNU sed only.

Answer (score 0):

If the text is structured, it might be enough with `cut`, e.g.:

```
(cut -c1-56 infile; cut -c62- infile) | sort -k2n
```

Output:

```
Bin   1 = 5778    669  753  731  743  752  727  736  667
Bin   5 =    2      2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
Bin   7 =   63     36    5    1    1    5    1    5    9    
Bin   9 =    0      0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
Bin  24 =    2      0    0    0    0    0    0    0    2    
Bin  31 =    0      0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
Bin  47 =   28      2    4    6    1    2    5    3    5    
Bin  70 =    1      0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
Bin  95 =    1      0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    
Bin 120 =    1      0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
Bin 121 =  162     49   13   11   10    3   10   12   54    
Bin 131 =    7      1    1    2    0    0    1    0    2
Bin 133 =    3      0    0    0    0    0    0    0    3    
Bin 141 =    6      0    0    0    1    0    1    2    2
Bin 560 =    1      0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    
Bin 620 =    1      0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
Bin 630 =    2      0    0    1    0    0    0    0    1    
Bin 1250 =    1     0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
Bin 1410 =    1     0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    
Bin 2004 =    1     0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
Bin 2240 =    1     0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    
Bin 2247 =    1     0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
Bin 2300 =    1     0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    
Bin 2309 =    1     0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
Bin 2310 =    3     1    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    
Bin 2602 =    1     0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: this works as well, thanks a lot for the input, appreciate it